# Send push notifications on app install in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter

Is it possible to send push notifications on app install in Flutter?
By app install, I mean that a user who has just downloaded the app but not opened it yet.

I'm using flutter_local_notifications to handle notifications on the foreground and firebase handles background notifications.
But both don't seem to help with app install case.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible task:

> There are a few preconditions which must be met before the application can receive message payloads via FCM:
>
> - The application must have opened at least once (to allow for
>   registration with FCM)

.

(c) [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage/#receiving-messages)